# Transfer Favorites List in IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate?

Tags: intellij-14

I'm migrating to a new machine, and I rely on my Favorites list to keep track of modules.

Does anyone know where that list is saved? It does not seem to be included in the import/export settings transfer.

Answer (score 0):

The favorites are stored under each project directory: `.idea/workspace.xml` (if I remember correctly).

If someone requests, I am happy to do further research on whether one can transfer and share the favorites across different machines.

Notes: unfortunately, this `workspace.xml` is not supposed to be shared across different machines. But, one might be able to isolate the favorites into a separate file.